# Azure App Settings not added to website when using virtual applications

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

According to the following screenshoot that shows all environment variables for an application and the configured app settings in the azure portal, i get the impression that app settings do not work with virtual applications. Is this intented?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what your left pane image is showing, but App Settings should apply to both the roo app and any virtual apps under it. They are based on environment variables (e.g. `foo` becomes `APPSETTING_foo`), which are available throughout the environment.

Comment: The left pane shows the environment variables written out in trace. No app settings are there :( thanks for confirming that it should work, guess i will have to figure out where i made a mistake.

Comment: I also see all the environment variables correct inside kudo using "cmd set". the application is a owin application if that makes any different. Not sure why AppSettings[key] is not resolving those from portal over web.config

Comment: got them to show now as environment variables - Environment.GetEnvironmentVariables() didnt  do it. Anyhow - could my problem be that I have = in the app setting key? i saw some bad parsing in kudo, maybe appsettings is doing the same.

Comment: Turned out be a bad idea to use = in app setting names :) thanks the  confirmation that it should work.

Comment: I think the issue is that Azure Portal App Settings might not work with owin apps at all, and that it is not related to it being a virtual application. i.e. you'd see the same with the root app I believe.

Comment: Actually got it working now, just had to remove the = from settings keys as they get parsed wrong when made environment variables.